# Unable to deploy a permission set with view all data permission

Tags: security

I have created a permission set with view all data system permission. When deploying it to production I am getting the error:

Permission View All Data depends on permission(s): Read Account, ...`<names of several standard and custom objects are listed here>`

I have done the following already:
Tried deploying through ANT and change set
Profile/permission set metadata API is same in both source and destination orgs
Read access to all objects is included in the permission set
Can someone please help?

Comment: is there are all the permission  read and edit for all the objects?

Comment: if you go to edit the permission set in the sandbox and click save - do you get any errors?  This could also be a sandbox at V40 and prod at v39 issue